# Store and Get byte[] array in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, arrays

I have a byte[] array. Suppose-

```
byte[] b = new byte[] {'11', '22', '33', '44'};
```

I want to store this array in Elasticsearch and get this byte array from elasticsearch by java. How can I do it? Please someone show me an example.

For example I want to see something like this-

```
SearchHit hit = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
byte[] b = (byte[]) hit.getSource().get("byte_array");
```

But I am getting this error. Please someone help me

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [B
```

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything and can't provide any research of investigation there is very little we can help with. If you're using a 3rd party library or product I would suggest looking at their examples first or Google for some examples.

Comment: I have tried like this :  
byte[] b = (byte[]) hit.getSource().get("byte_array");

but this shows:  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [B